# Стиль элемента wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть скрипт, который прописывает стиль на элемент инлайн (отображает element.style), мне нужно его отключить. Пытался найти через Хром => Break On=> attribute modifications, но ничего не выдало(может я не понимаю) Есть альтернативный вариант решения?
В директории сервера поиск по этим параметрам результата не дал
[image: скрин]

Comment: Возможно найдётся если ты задашь вопрос так, чтобы не только тебе было понятно о чем речь.

Comment: Сайт на движке wordpress, хочу поменять стиль элемента, но судя по всему для этого элемента применяется скрипт, т.к. стиль отображает как inline (т.е. прописанный скриптом как я понял) хочу найти нужный мне срипт и изменить стиль

Comment: С таким пояснением тебе к телепатам.

Comment: Почему не сказать по теме, что конкретно не понятно в том, что я описал? С такими ответами лучше никому не будет

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Попробую объяснить по-другому, есть тема на вордпресс дочерняя, хочу изменить стиль элемента, но параметр для элемента прикрепляется скриптом. Пытался найти по значению параметра в папке сервера, но всё не то. Как узнать какой скрипт вешает стиль на элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Используй командную строку для поиска по директории где установлен сайт.
Ну или скачай плагин, тему - что там у тебя и найди поиском по файлу нужный инлайн css
Если "скрипт" это php - то никакие брейкпойнты или events в браузере не покажут.

Comment: Искал в директории сайта и в бд mysql ничего не находит

Comment: Как найти тогда этот стиль? Если поиск в директории не помогает?

Comment: значит ищешь неверно или не там

Comment: С помощью какого инструмента ищешь в директории? Сам пользуюсь Atom

Comment: netbeans, php storm